# using django template lanuage to realize greater and less

Tags: django, templates, tags

papis

i have a dict here

```
dict = {1: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
        2: [2,4,5,6,7,8,9,0],
        3: [5,2,4,6,12,3,7,6]}
```

i want show it on my page 
so i using template as follows:

```
    {%for item in dict.items%}
    <tr>
    <td>{{item.0}}</td>
    {%for v in item.1%}
    here ,i dont know how to handle
    if last column and v >5
    <td color = 'red'>{{v}}</td>
    else
    <td>{{v}}</td>
   {%endfor%}
</tr>
{%endfor%}
```

as you see,i  want the last column turn red text if its value is greater than 5

how can i realize this ,i google and found nothing

thanks all bro.

when i did as Daniel told:

```
  {%for item in dict.items%}
    <tr>
    <td>{{item.0}}</td>
    {%for v in item.1%}
   {%if forloop.last and v > 5%}
    <td color = 'red'>{{v}}</td>
    {%else%}
     <td >{{v}}</td>
     {%endif%}
    else
    <td>{{v}}</td>
   {%endfor%}
</tr>
{%endfor%}
```

it told me the errors:

```
Could not parse the remainder: '>5' from '>5'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://10.64.41.134:8000/monthlyinfo/
Django Version:     1.3
Exception Type:     TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    

Could not parse the remainder: '>5' from '>5'
```

what is the problem?
thanks again
crafet

Comment: newbie say thank u, for editing code,Daniel

Answer (score 4):

```
{% if forloop.last and v > 5 %}
```

**Edit** You need some spaces. Do it exactly as I have above, and it parses fine.

Generally, your code would be better - and more readable - if you followed [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) style for spaces around operators.

Comment: Daniel,i was told errors here:Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://10.64.41.134:8000/monthlyinfo/
Django Version:  1.3
Exception Type:  TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:  

Could not parse the remainder: '>4.5' from '>4.5'

Exception Location:  C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in __init__, line 502
Python Executable:  C:\Python26\python.exe
Python Version:  2.6.7