# m learning..how to check in html file with jinja format ? it gives me error Could not parse the remainder: '>4000' from 'x.price>4000'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

```
{%for x in dest%}
                <div class="destination item">
                    <div class="destination_image">
                        <img src="{{baseurl}}/{{x.image}}" alt="">

                        {% if x.price > 4000%}
                        <div class="spec_offer text-center"><a href="#">Special Offer</a></div>
                        {%endif%}
                    </div>
                    <div class="destination_content">
                        <div class="destination_title"><a href="{% static 'destinations.html'%}">{{x.name}}</a></div>
                        <div class="destination_subtitle"><p>{{x.desc}}</p></div>
                        <div class="destination_price">{{x.price}}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
```

What is the problem at if statement above?? i tried to access the line special offer  but error says couldnot parse the remainder.

Comment: `{% if x.price > 4000 %}` use space around this.

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6818099/using-django-template-lanuage-to-realize-greater-and-less